# Push notifications as separate service in React native

Tags: android, ios, npm, react-native, push-notification

Currently I am developing a React native application.I want to write an npm package for FCM Notifications so that I should be able to use that package in any project by just passing required info to that package like API key[Without Mentioning services in Android manifest and linking in Main application etc]. And I should be able to get callback whenever I Receive notification.

First of all Is it possible ? If it is possible how can we do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fcm

I am using react-native-fcm and it works great for me.